# How to create a template that takes two different signatures for a callback

Tags: c++, templates

I have an executor that takes a function to run. It supports two signatures depending on whether the callback wants the session object.

```
template<typename T, typename S>
T run(const std::function<T(Client&)>& f, S s);

template<typename T, typename S>
T run(const std::function<T(Client&, const S&)>& f, S s);
```

I want to have a function wrap these two (say for retries) but I don’t want to write it twice since they are the same:

```
template <typename T, typename S>
T runWithRetry(const std::function<T(Client&)>& f, S s) {
  for (;;) {
    try {
      return run(f, s);
    } catch (Retry &e) {}
  }
}

template <typename T, typename S>
T runWithRetry(const std::function<T(Client&, const S&)>& f, S s) {
  for (;;) {
    try {
      return run(f, s);
    } catch (Retry &e) {}
  }
}
```

This is the actual problem I want to solve.

I tried making the callback a template but then I needed a way to get the return type:

```
template <typename F, typename S>
return_type<F>::type runWithRetry(const F& f, S s);
```

So how to implement return_type? I wanted something like:

```
template <typename F, typename S> struct return_type {
  using type = decltype(std::declval<F>(declval<Client>)) || decltype(std::declval<F>(declval<Client>, declval<S>)
}
```

But I couldn’t figure out how to express that.

I can use C++20.

Comment: invoke_result_t

Comment: if you're actually using `std::function`, there is already member type `result_type`

Comment: @jeffgarrett the problem with invoke_result_t is that there are two possible expressions and I don't know how to combine them

Comment: Got ya. I would probably just use decltype(run(f, s))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you can use C++20, then you don't need to worry about the return type, it can be deduced for you using `auto`.  That gives you

```
template <typename F, typename S>
auto runWithRetry(const F& f, S s) {
  for (;;) {
    try {
      return run(f, s);
    } catch (Retry &e) {}
  }
}
```

And now the return type will be the deduced return type of `run(f, s)`.  If `run` can return a reference, and you want to keep that, then you need to use `decltype(auto)` as the return type instead of just `auto`.

Comment: Should probably be `decltype(auto)`. In OP's original code it might have reference return type.

Comment: @user17732522 They don't in the OP but I've added about using that if they have the need.